# group data within specific range in excel

Tags: excel

Suppose I have below data

```
1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,5
```

I want to split it into different groups based on their occurrence count.

Range, occurrence count

```
0-1 = 1
1-3=5
3-5=2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `FREQUENCY` function in excel. Select all the cells where you want the range to be displayed.  Press <kbd>F2</kbd> to go into edit mode and enter the following formula and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=FREQUENCY(G8:G17,RIGHT(H8:H10,1)+0)
```

Here `G8:G17` is the data array and `H8:H10` is the bin array or range array. Let me know if you want any further explanation.

Here is my solution snapshot. 
[image: snapshot].